# Go through array in for loop and break when item is found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with my for loop not working right.

Basically I am find the users scroll position, and if its less then a certain number in an array I want to scroll to that position. My first two items in the array work fine. but if I scroll to the second last item it stays there for a second and then animates to the last item as well.

Here is my code

arrayPercent for example could have these numbers in it 794, 1588, 2383, 3177

```
//Scroll postion
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft; 
        //
        for(var j = 0; j <= numTotalPages; j++){
            if(lastScrollLeft <= arrayPercent[j]){
                console.log(arrayPercent[j]);
                numCurrentPage = j+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
        var TEMPcurrent = 'page'+numCurrentPage;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollLeft: $('#'+TEMPcurrent).offset().left
        }, 250);
    }, 500));
});
```

Comment: Oh when I mean scroll to that position I mean scroll to the next Div item.

Comment: Edit your post instead of making comments about updates.

Comment: It'd be a good idea to declare "lastScrollLeft" with `var` in the "ready" handler; it's not valid in strict mode to implicitly create a global variable like that. (Probably not relevant to your current problem of course.)

Comment: What is the relationship between "numTotalPages" and the array "arrayPercent"?

Comment: Right now I have numTotalPages = 4 and then that will fill in arrayPercent like so

    for(var i = 1; i <= numTotalPages; i++){ 
   arrayPercent[i-1] = parseInt((browserW*i)*.60); 
  }